# c# Convert Dictionary<string, List<>> to Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting

how can I append string to Json output in c#(linq) way

```
// Dictionary<string, List<object>>
var res = results.Where(x=>x.ConfidenceScore>0)
                            .GroupBy(x=>x.PropertyName)
                            .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key, 
                                    g=> g.Select(x=>x.Value.ToString()).ToList()
                                    ); 

>>> ??? res["OcrText"] = doc.Text;
Console.Out.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res));
```

currently I have to copy whole dictionary to another be element to cast types

```
Dictionary<string, object> ugly = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (var item in res)
{
  ugly.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
}
ugly["OcrText"] = doc.Text;
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly and you just want to convert `Dictionary<string, List<object>>` to `Dictionary<string, object>()`

You could use [`ToDictionary`](http://Enumerable.ToDictionary%20Method)

```
var result = dict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => (object)x.Value);
```

However its debatable why you would want to do this

or maybe you want

```
var res = results.Where(x => x.ConfidenceScore > 0)
               .GroupBy(x => x.PropertyName)
               .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                  g => (object)g.Select(x => x.Value.ToString()).ToList()
               );
```

Though on saying that, i'm pretty confused by the question, and i think you need to clarify things more